# Pass DTO for GET Request in REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I have a REST method for search users. Right now I am having following signature for the REST method:

```
MyResponse GetUsers(UserSearchDTO search, int pageno, int totalrecords);
```

i.e it is accepting one object of `UserSearchDTO`, pageno and totalrecords param. The URL will look like

```
myapp/users?pageno={pageno}&totalrecords={totalrecords}
```

The end client will send "PUT" request for this service like:

`myapp/users?pageno=1&totalrecords=10` and along with it it will pass xml data posted of UserSearchDTO like

```
<UserSearchDTO><Department>d</Department><Name>abc</Name></UserSearchDTO>
```

Is this a good architecture i.e in order to get users I am using "PUT" request type. The reason for doing this is because end client has to pass UserSearchDTO in xml form?

The other approach which I'm thinking is pure "GET" i.e instead of using `UserSearchDTO` I should have the following signature:

```
  MyResponse GetUsers(string department,string name,...., int pageno, int totalrecords);
```

and the end client will call it like:
myapp/users?department=d&name=abc&......&pageno=1&totalrecords=10

Comment: pageno and totalrecords are both of int type i.e they accepts integer only.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of writing my first REST service, so I am no expert, but in my opinion, I think it would be best to use a GET request, since that is exactly what you are doing -- getting data from the server.  This will make it easier for other developers to support the app, instead of trying to figure out why you used PUT for a basic data retrieval.

If possible, I suggest that you try casting the UserSearchDTO XML as a string on the client and passing it to the GetUsers method as a string, then load the string into an XmlDocument() on the server and parse it into the DTO.  Then your method signature would look like:

```
MyResponse GetUsers(string userSearchXmlString, int pageno, int totalrecords);
```

Comment: Please do not send XML as part of the uri.. that's just wrong. Instead use single query parameters, and don't add something too complex. That's not what GET operations are for in RESTful services.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using WCF REST.  With WCF REST, you have to implement the query mechanisms yourself as you are attempting to do.  Have you considered using ASP.NET Web API?  In Web API, your `GetUsers()` method simply needs to return an `IQueryable<User>` and Web API wraps that with [OData querying capability](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/odata-core/#1023_Querying_Collections) which handles projection, filtering, sorting, aggregating and paging for you.